# Checking the distribution of input variables with missing data imputed in exploratory data analysis

Tags: distributions, data-transformation, missing-data, exploratory-data-analysis

Suppose there are missing data in input variables and the missing rates are relatively high, we use some certain value to impute the missing info. When we check the distribution for input variables in EDA, do we check the distribution of non-missing values only or check the distribution for all values with missing data imputed?

There are some tutorial mentioning using -999 to impute missing data. The distribution for input variables may look quite skewed if using rather small value like -999 as imputed values. Do we choose appropriate data transformation method considering all the values with missing data imputed?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: For what purpose are you checking the distributions of the variables? What tutorials are talking about using -999 to replace missing values? That sounds like a notation to handle the coding, not a recommended replacement procedure. The common advice is to use multiple imputation to replace missing data, not replace with a single value.

Comment: I want to pick appropriate transformation method for the variables. For example, in order to choose lambda for box-cox transformation, I need to check the variable distributions. I see a lot of Kaggle kernel using -999 or 0 to fill in missing values.